# Angular2: how do display character count on reactive form input

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular2 reactive forms, and I want to display a character count of a `textarea` as the user types.

I was hoping to just be able to include the form control's `name.length` in my html like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="incidentDescription">Brief Description of Incident</label>
  <textarea id="incidentDescription" formControlName="incidentDescription" required [attr.maxLength]="maxIncidentDescriptionLength"></textarea>
  <small><code>{{alaynaPage.incidentDescription.length}}</code> of <code>{{maxIncidentDescriptionLength}}</code> characters</small>
</div>
```

This "works" however the `length` of the form control lags one keystroke behind. So for example if I type `a` into the textarea `{{alaynaPage.incidentDescription.length}}` is 0.  If i then type `b` (so string is `ab`) `{{alaynaPage.incidentDescription.length}}` is now 1.

How do I get this to work as expected?

I got it to work via a hack but there has to be an easier way:

```
//in component:  
theLength: number = 0;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.buildForm();

    (this.alaynaPageForm.controls['incidentDescription'] as FormControl).valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      // do something with value here
      this.theLength = value.length;
    });
  }

//in my html:
<small class="form-text text-muted"><code>{{theLength}}</code> of <code>{{maxIncidentDescriptionLength}}</code> characters</small>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You just need to use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-reference-variables)

```
<textarea id="incidentDescription" formControlName="incidentDescription" #incidentDescription></textarea>
<small class="form-text text-muted"><code>{{incidentDescription.value.length}}</code> of <code>{{maxIncidentDescriptionLength}}</code> characters</small>
```

Comment: And what about if the control was created with "new FormControl(null, { updateOn: 'blur' })"

Answer (score 3):

You want a hack, here's the hack. Use this:

```
{{alaynaPageForm.value?.incidentDescription?.length}}
```

Comment: Yikes - that is a hack.  I just figured out how to do it cleanly. See my ans

Comment: Why is that a hack? Just because it uses the typescript coalescing-operator?